# Apex 5.1 Plug-ins not working

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am busy with a migration from 4.2 to 5.1. I installed Oracle 12c, Tomcat 8.5 and ords.  Apex works but I cannot use any plug-ins (so far).

For testing I installed SkillBuilders Super LOV (3.0).  It does not work.  What I see is only a text field and two little buttons with no icons. Probably a config problem. Any ideas ?

Here is an image describing the issue :
http://pepitoto.000webhostapp.com/images/plugins.png
[what I have What I should have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ2H2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I installed glassfish and deployed the ords.war and the i.war.  I had exactly the same problem as on Tomcat
So my problem was beneath and probably resulting of a wrong setting in ORDS or in Apex installation.

After 2 Days of tries and errors I found the reason.  So I describe the troubleshooting I found. Maybe it can help someone else.
It was only due to a parameter in the ords config (ords_params.properties):
db.hostname=localhost (Is correct)
db.hostname=epsvlwl135 (The name of the server; was wrong. Apex worked but the plug-ins didn't)

Answer (score 0):

- Thanks for solution offered by Eric S, yet, as I used remote database, it was not applicable in my case.

What Helped me is :

- Stop Tomcat ( and also Apache if you use them both ).
- Delete both ords.war and ords folder from your tomcat webapps directory ( on my server : /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.5/webapps)
- Delete your old ords directory you extracted from ords.x.x.zip installation  file including config dir  ( on my server I have unzipped everything : /home/oracle/ords , so I deleted this folder)
- Unzip ords.x.x.zip to ords directory.
- Start confiuration by java -jar ords.war install advanced.
- Once finished, copy the newly created ords.war to your tomcat webapps directory ( on my server : /usr/share/tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.5/webapps)
- restart tomcat.
- Credits to : [Morten Braten Blog](https://ora-00001.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/installing-oracle-xe-ords-and-apex-on-centos-linux-part-two.html)